# How to select the first n elements from Ruby array that satisfy a predicate?

Tags: ruby

I want to get all items from an array, which satisfy a predicate. Once I see an element that doesn't satisfy, I should stop iterating. For example:

```
[1, 4, -9, 3, 6].select_only_first { |x| x > 0}
```

I'm expecting to get: `[1, 4]`

Comment: It's good to become familiar with all the methods on Array and Enumerable. It will save you lots of time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you want :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> pry
[1] pry(main)> [1, 4, -9, 3, 6].take_while { |x| x > 0}
=> [1, 4]
[2] pry(main)>
```

Here is the documentation :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~> ri Array#take_while

= Array#take_while

(from ruby site)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.take_while { |arr| block }  -> new_ary
  ary.take_while                  -> Enumerator

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Passes elements to the block until the block returns nil or false, then stops
iterating and returns an array of all prior elements.

If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.

See also Array#drop_while

  a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
  a.take_while { |i| i < 3 }  #=> [1, 2]


lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're exploring other solution, this works too:

```
[1, 4, -9, 3, 6].slice_before { |x| x <= 0}.to_a[0]
```

You have to change x > 0 to x <=0.

Comment: You can replace `to_a[0]` with `first`.

Answer (score 0):

That was an excellent answer Arup. My method is slightly more complicated.

```
numbers = [1,4,-9,3,6]

i = 0
new_numbers = []
until numbers[i] < 0
  new_numbers.push(numbers[i])
  i+= 1
end

=> [1,4]
```

Comment: this is not really the ruby/functional way to do things. ruby is meant to be elegant.